# how do i manually authenticate and log in a user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

```
    if request.method=='POST':
        try:        
            email=request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            if StudentUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                user = StudentUser.objects.get(email=email)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    user = auth.authenticate(email=email)
                    if user is not None:
                        auth.login(request,user)
                        messages.success(request,'Successfully Loggedin')
                        return redirect('/')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request,'Password does not match')
                    return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'No Account registered with this mail')
                return redirect('login')
        except Exception as problem:
            messages.error(request,problem)
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request,'login.html')
```

This above code i am trying to authenticate the user manually, but it is not working. i want to authenticate a user by manually checking the password.
How can i do it?

** when I am passing the password in auth.authenticate function it is showing password does not match error

Answer (score 2):

You should pass password as argument to authenticate method

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users)

```
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

> Use authenticate() to verify a set of credentials. It takes
> credentials as keyword arguments, username and password for the
> default case, checks them against each authentication backend, and
> returns a User object if the credentials are valid for a backend.

Comment: when i am passing it is giving me password does not match error and returning none type object. The thing is that i want to have two different user table one for admin one for common user. for that i haven't set this custom user at settings.py file to override the inbuilt user models

Comment: there is simply enough documentation of how to override Django default user model and also how to write custom authentication backend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend